# spine.js difficulties with jquery dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, spine.js

I am trying to give spine.js a spin but I am having difficulties when including jQuery as a dependency. Basically I reference `"jquery": "~1.8.3"` in `package.json` and `"jquery"` in `slug.json`, then I run `npm install .`

Fire up hem server, but when I load my app it crashes on me with the following output:

```
 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/hem/lib/resolve.js:43
      throw "Cannot find module: " + request + ". Have you run `npm install .`
                                             ^
Cannot find module: url. Have you run `npm install .` ?
```

This seems to be related to node.js `url` module, and how hem uses [node/lib/module.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/node/blob/master/lib/module.js#L160) to resolve/load? dependencies?.

Below you'll find particular code that crashes on `hem/lib/resolve.js`

```
module.exports = function(request, parent) {
var dir, filename, id, paths, _, _ref1;
if (parent == null) {
  parent = repl;
}
_ref1 = Module._resolveLookupPaths(request, parent), _ = _ref1[0], paths = _ref1[1];
filename = Module._findPath(request, paths);
dir = filename;
if (!filename) {
  throw "Cannot find module: " + request + ". Have you run `npm install .` ?";
}
while (__indexOf.call(invalidDirs, dir) < 0 && __indexOf.call(modulePaths, dir) < 0) {
  dir = dirname(dir);
}
if (__indexOf.call(invalidDirs, dir) >= 0) {
  throw "Load path not found for " + filename;
}
id = filename.replace("" + dir + "/", '');
return [modulerize(id, filename), filename];
```

};

The call to `Module._findPath(request, paths)` returns false being request = "url" and paths= "."

I have tried manually installing node.js url module, using npm both locally and even globally and is still failing in the same way. I have also tried including jquery under lib instead of automatic management but it gives the same results.

Answer (score 0):

NPM is not for frontend development, as far as Spine.js is :) You should install Twitter Bower - https://github.com/twitter/bower. You can do it system-wide (`npm install bower -g`), or locally `{"devDepencies": {"bower": "0.6.6"}}` to your `package.json` and `npm install`. Then create `component.json` with depencies for spine and jquery. Run `bower install` or `./node_modules/.bin/bower install .` after. You'll find spine and jquery in `components` folder.

Comment: thanks for pointing to the bower resource, however the dependencies are not really failing to install, it seems that the failure is on hem (https://github.com/maccman/hem/tree/version0_2). Hem is a tool that not only handles dependencies but is also supposed to aid on development by wrapping up all of them on one file as you require them on your code during development.